# UIImage description

Tags: ios, ios4, uiimage

I'm new in the iphone programming. I want to add description of uiimage. Can I do that and how? I search in apple documentation but didn't find how to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably add an `UILabel` with your description, just beneath your `UIImageView` with your `UIImage`.

---

Can you just get the `text link to the video` and `thumbnail uiimage object` and pass it to the next `viewcontroller`, whether using custom initialization or storing the two in `AppDelegate`'s vars?

Comment: No I want to add meta information. I don't want to user can see it and to add it to my design.

Comment: give me an example of the information, you may need to implement core data if it is too complex

Comment: I want to make thumbnail from video and save link of the video.

Comment: So you would have pairs (txtLocationOfIMG;txtVideoLink) ?

Comment: Yes I'll have pairs (txtLocationOfIMG;txtVideoLink)

Comment: Where are those pairs going to be created from? Will they be local to the app?

Comment: Yes. I want to choose video from my library and make thumbnail with link of the video.

Comment: What will "link of the video" contain?

Comment: Location of the video on the device.

Comment: That will be all using `UIImagePickerController`, right? and where do you want to store all these pairs? Do they need to persist for the next time the user uses the app?

Comment: No I want to use them in next screen. And then send the video to the server.